# Path integral as a functional determinant

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, grassmann-numbers, functional-determinants

In Peskin and Schroeder on pg. 304, the authors call the fermionic path integral:
\begin{equation} 
\int {\cal D} \bar{\psi} {\cal D} \psi \exp \left[ i \int \,d^4x \bar{\psi} ( i \gamma_\mu D^\mu - m ) \psi \right] 
\end{equation} 
a functional determinant,
\begin{equation} 
\det \left( i \gamma_\mu D^\mu - m \right). 
\end{equation} 
I've never heard this way of thinking about it. Why would the generating functional be a functional determinant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the path integral ${\cal Z}$ is an infinite-dimensional version of a [Grassmann-odd Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_integral)

$$\int \!\mathrm{d}^n \bar{\theta} ~\mathrm{d}^n\theta ~e^{\sum_{i,j=1}^n\bar{\theta}_i ~M^i{}_j ~\theta^j}~\propto~\det(M), $$

where the indices $i,j$ can be interpreted as [DeWitt's condensed notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeWitt_notation).

Comment: Just to add to @Qmechanic's perfect answer. You can also see the discussion in the appendix of Ramond's QFT book. It is also interesting that the integral for real Grassmann variables gives the Pfaffian.